# Provision of switching Devel::Cover on/off

Tags: perl, perl-module, devel-cover

While using Devel::Cover in a test code which tests CodeA, does Devel::Cover have an option of switching the coverage off. Is there a way to switch the coverage module on or off as per user?

Test code tests CodeA.
Devel::Cover commands are embedded in Test code whenever CodeA commands get tested.

Does Devel::Cover include any provision where this coverage collection can be switched on or off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to turn coverage on and off at runtime, but it seems that I have forgotten to document it.  However, it is tested, so you can see how to use it there:

https://github.com/pjcj/Devel--Cover/blob/master/t/internal/criteria.t

This isn't exactly the same as if Devel::Cover had never been loaded, but rather it just stops Devel::Cover collecting coverage information for the criteria which are turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still confused as to the running part and making it stop after looking at your testcase.Do I have to call set_ coverage with none parameter followed by get_coverage everytime before a perl -MDevel::Cover command  to remove coverage? Or does the remove_coverage option work?