# How do I collect coverage from child processes when running `cover -test`, and not otherwise? (Devel::Cover)

Tags: code-coverage, spawn, perl, devel-cover

(I think I've seen the answer to this, but I can't find it again.  The closest I have come across is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24420346/2877364)).

I am hacking on [prt](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-PRT/script/prt) and am trying to get full coverage data for my changes.  Some of my new tests call `system($^X, 'prt', ...)` to run child processes.  I then test the output of those processes.  However, Devel::Cover does not collect coverage data in the child processes.  How do I collect that data, without causing Devel::Cover to run when I do a regular `make test`?  Currently I have an ugly workaround (see below), but I think there must be a simpler way.

A full MCVE is [here](https://github.com/cxw42/multi-process-devel-cover-test).  Command line to copy, for your convenience:

```
git clone https://github.com/cxw42/multi-process-devel-cover-test.git ; cd multi-process-devel-cover-test ; perl Makefile.PL ; make ; cover -test
```

Comment out line 11 of `t/01-help.t` for the workaround described below.

**Edit** The reason I am using `system` is to get to 100% coverage on `-h`/`--help`/`--version`.  Those switches are handled by [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long), which calls `exit()` automatically.  If necessary, I can use `-exitval=>NOEXIT` and handle the exit in my own code.

#### Things that don't work

**`PERL5OPT`**

```
$ PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1 cover -test
/home/cxw/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perlcygbrew-5.26.2-1/bin/cover shouldn't be run with coverage turned on.
```

**`HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES`+`cover`**

```
$ HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1 cover -test
...
t/01-help.t .. # Devel::Cover not covering
...
----- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
File    stmt   bran   cond    sub    pod   time  total
----- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
Total    n/a    n/a    n/a    n/a    n/a    n/a    n/a
----- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```

**`HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES`+EUMM `make test`**

```
$ HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1 make test
...
t/01-help.t .. # Devel::Cover not covering
...
$ (export HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1 ; make test)
...
t/01-help.t .. # Devel::Cover not covering
...
```

#### Current workaround

At present, the only way I have found is to manually add `-MDevel::Cover` to the command line when I call `system`.  Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24429239/2877364) and [the corresponding tests](https://github.com/pjcj/Devel--Cover/blob/7f365d2e412675bc741adef43d6cc9353cf1885b/t/internal/criteria.t#L10-L18), I have the following workaround:

```
# Detect whether Devel::Cover is running
my $is_covering = !!(eval 'Devel::Cover::get_coverage()');
my @perl = ($^X, $is_covering ? ('-MDevel::Cover=-silent,1') : ());
diag $is_covering ? 'Devel::Cover running' : 'Devel::Cover not covering';

# Pass the Devel::Cover option, if any, to the child process
system(@perl, 'prt', ...);
```

In the MCVE, the workaround is [here](https://github.com/cxw42/multi-process-devel-cover-test/blob/5395b4f0894790db01773a4f90c4713110f39e63/t/01-help.t#L9-L12) and it is used [here](https://github.com/cxw42/multi-process-devel-cover-test/blob/5395b4f0894790db01773a4f90c4713110f39e63/t/01-help.t#L25).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this, or something similar, is probably about the best you can do.

Devel::Cover is pretty much designed as a development tool and, as such, has the assumption that you will be testing one project at a time.  It seems that you are really wanting to test two projects here.  If that's not the case then perhaps there is a better way of combining the parts than using system?

But if your current solution is the best way of combining this code then I'm not sure there's a better way to get complete coverage.  You could perhaps be explicit and set an environment variable if you want coverage, for example, or you could set $PERL5OPT rather than change the system call, but essentially that's the same solution.

Comment: Paul, thanks!  Question edited re. `system`.  Is there any better/recommended/documented way to detect running under `cover` than my `eval 'Devel::Cover::get_coverage()'`?

Comment: There is no documented way to know whether Devel::Cover is running, nor is there a recommended way.  My reasons are twofold.  First, I really don't want people to do anything special when collecting coverage - collecting coverage should, ideally, be transparent to the user.  And secondly, I don't remember ever coming across a case where I have thought that the only way, or even the superior way, to solve a problem is to do something different when collecting coverage.  As far as a better way is concerned, I would probably check for $Devel::Cover::VERSION but what you have is not bad.  ENOSPC