# Devel::Cover - Save coverage data before the program ends

Tags: perl, devel-cover

**Question:** Can I force `Devel::Cover` to dump/save coverage data within the code, e.g. `cover->dump_coverage()`, before the program terminates?

**Context:** I want to extract coverage reports even if I forcefully end the Perl process with `kill -9`, to which `Devel::Cover` [cannot save its coverage data](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1164092). I have found that `Devel::Cover` has a method to [turning it off/on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420346/provision-of-switching-develcover-on-off) during runtime, but that doesn't seem to force the module to dump its data. Does it have another method to dump the coverage instead?

Comment: Why do you care about coverage data from a process that behaves so badly that you have to use SIGKILL instead of SIGTERM? (If you sent SIGTERM, you could use `$SIG{TERM} = sub { exit(128|15); };`)

Comment: The `SIGKILL` can't be caught.  While I don't know details of related  `Devel::Cover` behavior, I'd expect that there is _nothing_ that _any_ software can do in response to it (a signal it can't trap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Devel::Cover side, call Devel::Cover::report().

Catching the signal is up to you...